# Role Based Access Control (RBAC) class design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was trying to create a Role Based Access Control and with some google search I found the solution to create User table, Role Table ,User Role table , Permission table and Role Permission table. But I don't find  much on class design perspective. For example I have an ADMIN Role(using inheritance by taking IRole as parent interface) do I need to create a separate class or should I create only Role class which record as Admin. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You should not inherit a new class for each role, you will have a list of roles and each role has a set of permissions and each user is associated to one or more roles, so it should be like:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Permission> Permissions{ get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum Permissions
{
    Read = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Add = 3,
    Delete = 4 //rest of your roles
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The list of permissions will be predefined and static in the database, you can't change it at the runtime as your code will depend on it. However, you can change the roles and associate users to roles.

In your code when you need to check if a User has an access to a specific resources, you will mark this resource with a Permission.

ex: In the following code, the user will access the code only if he has the Update Permissions.

```
public void UpdateItem(Item item)
{
   var currentUser = //get the user from the database or session
   if(currentUser.Roles.Any(r=>r.Permissions.Any(p=>p.Id == (int)Permissions.Update))
   {
     // do the logic
   }
   else
   {
     // show access denied
   }
}
```